# Neo4J Cypher - Find integer attributes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

### Background

I have nodes which have been recording a specific attribute as LONG and I want them to be recorded as INT - I have amended my system's input code to now record them as INT, however I am looking to check Neo4J for anomalies.

### The Data

I now have a mix of data, where some have been created as "int" some as STR and some are even null (which is ok in my data-structure)

```
CREATE (n:logs{value: "example", records: "30"})
    , (n:logs{value: "example", records: 30})
    , (n:logs{value: "example", records: null})
RETURN n
```

### The Problem

I tried to verify if the system is now writing the "records" attribute as INT rather than string, so I tried the following query;

```
WITH datetime("2021-06-18T06:00:00").epochMillis AS threshold
MATCH(n:logs)
WHERE n.records <> tointeger(n.records)
COUNT(n)
```

This returns 1 - my *NULL* record, for some reason. But NOT the STR, as I would have expected.

I then try the following (18th June being the date of the update to my input system);

```
WITH datetime("2021-06-18T06:00:00").epochMillis AS threshold
MATCH(n:logs)
WHERE n.records = tointeger(n.records)
COUNT(n)
```

And this returns 0 - which again, I am not sure why.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong and how can I get to where I need to go. Which is ultimately to;

1. Check the system is saving as INT going forwards
2. Change all the pre-existing records from STR to INT.

I assume for #2 is will be something like

```
MATCH(n:logs)
WHERE n.records <> tointeger(n.records)
SET n.records = tointeger(n.records)
```

### Additional Info

- Community edition
- Version X.x.x
- No addins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query to update to integer is correct.

To clarify your assumptions, please run below queries in your neo4j desktop or browser and you will see what is going on.

```
 1. RETURN toInteger("2021-06-18T06:00:00")

 2. RETURN toInteger(null)
```

Both of them will return NULL.  It means your claim below is NOT true

> This returns 1 - my NULL record, for some reason. But NOT the
> STR, as I would have expected.

You did return 1 but is it the string value of records ('30') rather than the NULL value.

Then when you run your query below

> WHERE n.records = tointeger(n.records)

> And this returns 0 - which again, I am not sure why.

It is because the integer value of a string date type is also NULL. Thus it will return no matching record.

If you want to count all nodes with non-integer attribute, including nulls then you can run below query.

```
MATCH(n:logs)
WHERE n.records <> tointeger(n.records) OR n.records is null
RETURN count(distinct n) as cnt

Result:  2
```

Remember, if n.records = "2021-06-18T06:00:00" then you need to convert it to an epoch value (the integer value of time in seconds or millis since 1/1/1970). If not, then tointeger(n.records) is null and will not match in your query.

Do something like below:

```
MATCH (n:logs)
WHERE tointeger(n.records) is null
SET n.records = datetime(n.records).epochMillis
RETURN n
```

Then do your original query (this is correct!), to clean up other non-integer values.

```
MATCH(n:logs)
WHERE n.records <> tointeger(n.records)
SET n.records = tointeger(n.records)
```